# Azure Devops Pipeline - deploy subscription level resources using Bicep, Bicep parameters file and override parameter in stage

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-bicep

Here is my situation:

I have a DevOps pipeline that goes Dev > Staging > Prod.

I have my bicep file, I have my bicepparam file.

Inside my bicepparam file, I have a default global parameter:

```
using 'main.bicep'
param workloadPrefix = 'work'
```

For my Pipeline I have the following:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  azureServiceConnection: 'connection'
  subscription: ''
  templateFile: './bicep/main.bicep'
  paramFile: './bicep/main.bicepparam'
  pool: 'Azure Pipelines'

stages:
- stage: Dev
  variables:
    location: 'location'
    name: 'Dev deployment'
    workloadPrefix: 'dev'
  jobs:
    - job: Dev
      pool:
        name: '$(pool)'
      steps:
      - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
        displayName: 'Deploy Bicep to Dev'
        inputs:
          deploymentScope: 'Subscription'
          azureResourceManagerConnection: '$(azureServiceConnection)'
          subscriptionId: '$(subscription)'
          location: '$(location)'
          csmFile: '$(templateFile)'
          csmParametersFile: '$(paramFile)'
          overrideParameters: '-workloadPrefix $(workloadPrefix)'
```

Here is my issue:

If I use AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3, which supports the overrideParameters flag, it doesn't support having the csmParametersFile as a bicepparam file, it requires a JSON file.

If I instead try and use AzureCLI@2:

```
  steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'Deploy Bicep to Dev'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '$(azureServiceConnection)'
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: | 
        az deployment sub create \
        --name '$(name)' \
        --location '$(location)' \
        --template-file '$(templateFile)' \
        --parameters '$(paramFile)' \
        --overrideParameters workloadPrefix='$(workloadPrefix)'
```

It doesn't support the --overrideParameters flag.

If I try to use Powershell, reading the documentation, it looks like the New-AzSubscriptionDeployment doesn't support it either.

Is there a way to do this? That is, use a bicepparam file, with a default parameter, that can get overriden by a particular pipeline stage?

Comment: you can just use the `--parameters` flag multipe times: `--parameters '$(paramFile)' --parameters workloadPrefix='$(workloadPrefix)'`

Comment: @Thomas - apparently not: ERROR: Can not use --parameters argument more than once when using a .bicepparam file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known limitation when using the Bicep deploy.

When you use the bicepparam file in bicep deploy, it doesn't support using the --overrideParameters flag.

For a workaround, you can convert the bicepparam file to json file in Pipeline with the following command: `bicep build-params main.bicepparam` .

It will create a main.json file based on the main.bicepparam file.

Then you can use the json file for deployment.

For example:

```
trigger: main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  azureServiceConnection: 'connection'
  subscription: ''
  templateFile: './bicep/main.bicep'
  paramFile: './bicep/main.bicepparam'
  pool: 'Azure Pipelines'

stages:
- stage: Dev
  variables:
    location: 'location'
    name: 'Dev deployment'
    workloadPrefix: 'dev'
  jobs:
    - job: Dev
      pool:
        name: '$(pool)'
      steps:
      - script: 'bicep build-params ./bicep/main.bicepparam '
       
        
      - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
        displayName: 'Deploy Bicep to Dev'
        inputs:
          deploymentScope: 'Subscription'
          azureResourceManagerConnection: '$(azureServiceConnection)'
          subscriptionId: '$(subscription)'
          location: '$(location)'
          csmFile: '$(templateFile)'
          csmParametersFile: 'filepath/main.json'
          overrideParameters: '-workloadPrefix $(workloadPrefix)'
```

**Note:** If you are not able to run bicep command, you can add this command: `az bicep install` to install bicep cli.

Comment: I just tried that - but unfortunately, it was throwing an error for the Parameters file :(

Comment: @TheDemonLord Can you share the error message with us? Then I will check it

Comment: The detected encoding for file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/bicep/main.json' is 'utf-8'
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidTemplate.
[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the template parameter 'environmentCode' at line '1' and column '331' is not provided. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-create-parameter-file for usage details.'.

Comment: And here's my Bicepparam file:
using 'main.bicep'

param workloadPrefix = 'work'
param environmentCode = 'test'

Comment: For the workloadPrefix  parameter, can it pass to main.bicep successfully? you can also try to define the environmentCode  in the AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment task and check if it can work. For example:  `overrideParameters: '-workloadPrefix $(workloadPrefix)' -environmentCode  test`

Comment: On the other hand, you can also check if the value in the newly created json file is correct.

Comment: I've checked the json file, it looks valid: {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "workloadPrefix": {
      "value": "work"
    },
    "environmentCode": {
      "value": "test"
    }}}

Comment: I've done some additional testing on this - it seems to be an issue with the task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 - as when I run the same template and JSON file with AzureCLI@2 and do an az deployment sub create with the same files - it goes through.

Comment: @TheDemonLord Glad to know that it can work when using the Azure CLI command. The issue can be related to the ARM template task itself.  If the answer can give you some help, you may consider accepting it. Thanks.